# Docusign is getting the exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: docusignapi

> ```
> import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
> import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
> import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultPars
> ```
>
> ---

er; import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter; import org.apache.commons.cli.Options; import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException; import com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi; import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.*; import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient; import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth; import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.OAuthToken; import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.UserInfo; import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.Account; import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException; import com.docusign.esign.model.Document; import com.docusign.esign.model.CarbonCopy; import com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeDefinition; import com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeSummary; import com.docusign.esign.model.Recipients; import com.docusign.esign.model.Signer; import com.docusign.esign.model.Tabs; import com.docusign.esign.model.SignHere;  import java.nio.file.Files; import java.nio.file.Paths; import java.util.*; import java.io.*; import java.awt.Desktop; import java.net.URI; import weblogic.logging.NonCatalogLogger;  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  import org.json.JSONArray; import org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject;  import weblogic.logging.NonCatalogLogger;  public class DsNewAuth {    public DsNewAuth() {     super();   }   NonCatalogLogger LOG = new NonCatalogLogger("DsNewAuth class");    public String getOauth(JSONObject jObj) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {     // Get information fro app.config     //  InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("docusign/app_config");     //  Properties prop = new Properties();     //  String fileName = "app_config";     //  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("app_config");     // prop.load(fis);     System.out.println("Inside the DsNewAuth class: ");      LOG.debug("Begin call to DocusignServiceClient.submitDocument");      try {       String rsaKeyFile = ;        // Get access token and accountId       LOG.debug("Inside the debugline1: ");       ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");       apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");       ArrayList < String > scopes = new ArrayList < String > ();       scopes.add("signature");       scopes.add("impersonation");       LOG.debug("Inside the debugline1.1: ");       //    byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(rsaKeyFile));       byte[] privateKeyBytes = rsaKeyFile.getBytes();       LOG.debug("Inside the debugline1.2: ");       String clientId = "f18b3b0c-9991-4289-84cb-8dfa6fec5478";       String userId = "b2ff84d5-29e8-40dc-b210-9b880ea6055a";       OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(         //  prop.getProperty(clientId),         //  prop.getProperty(userId),         clientId,         userId,         scopes,         privateKeyBytes,         3600);       LOG.debug("Inside the debugline1.3: ");       String accessToken = oAuthToken.getAccessToken();       UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(accessToken);       LOG.debug("Inside the debugline1.4: ");       String accountId = userInfo.getAccounts().get(0).getAccountId();       LOG.debug("AccessToken: " + accessToken);     } catch (Exception e) {       System.out.println("Inside the catch exception: ");       System.out.println(e.getMessage());       LOG.debug("Inside the catch exception: ");       LOG.debug("Error!!!  ");       LOG.debug(e.getMessage());       // System.out.println ("Error!!!  ");       // System.out.println (e.getMessage());     }     return "success";   } }

```
getting below error

Root cause of ServletException.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.\<init\>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at 

org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
at 

org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
at 

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
at 

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
at 

org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
Truncated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the location of your key file:

```
String rsaKeyFile = ;
```

Also, use the debugger to determine which line of your source is causing the exception

Comment: The rsaKeyFile variable value i have provided in my code while i am testing,
 in the above post i have not mentioned

Comment: Ok, fine. Your next task is to use your debugger to determine your source line where the error is being raised. And update your question accordingly  Then we can better help you.